# Laptop doesn't go to sleep and doesn't respond after idle screen timeout only while connected to AC power

Tags: windows-10, bios, motherboard, sleep, cmos

I'm having HP Pavilion Laptop 15-cc1xx(Win 10 Home 64 bit), and it worked completely fine until I did a BIOS update to F.34 from F.33 and then this weird issue started the laptop doesn't go to sleep, only screen turns off but fans and power LED is on but never wakes or responds to any inputs, same thing happens when left idle and screen turns off, the strange thing here is this only happens while plugged in, otherwise in battery it works completely fine I don't have any issue. I've tried all the fixes suggested on the web(Updating drivers, factory reset,....etc), nothing is left to try out now and this post is my last hope. I even tried dual booting to Ubuntu OS by installing it alongside Win 10 and the same (exactly the same) issue was present in Ubuntu OS also.

Now my question is whether this is happening because of some corrupt BIOS update? because this was not present before updating BIOS. Does BIOS has any function when the OS performs sleep mode operation or when it turns off screen after idle time?
And I'm not able to downgrade the BIOS cause HP restricts it if it has security improvements so I'm stuck in this version until the next update.

Comment: Try the F.35 BIOS  (https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/BIOS-VERSION-F-35-DOWNLOAD/td-p/7689858)  See if (a) that is for your model and (b) if it resolves your issue.

Comment: No it's not for my laptop model my laptop model is HP Pavilion Laptop 15-cc1xx, and I've seen the HP software and drivers page for this model this F.34 is the latest version released on July 2020.

Comment: You probably should call HP Support. Generally here we cannot fix BIOS problems.

Comment: Yes I know I've contacted hp but even they are not having any ideas now after giving all trouble shooting steps which were all in vain. So now I'm just asking whether the bios is responsible for any sleep operations?btw I don't have any option other than to wait for the next version of bios update.